# How to use excel down row code

Tags: string, vba, excel

i have written a code =

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A" & ":E").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").range("A1").
```

This code helps me to copy content (in column A to E) in Sheet1 to another Sheet2. It gets copied in A1. However, the code copies everything in column A to E. There are some contents below specfic row that i don't want. 
I have applied End(xlDown).Row code as follows:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A" & ":E").End(xlDown).Row.Copy 
Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").range("A1")
```

However, it is giving me run time error

```
'424': Object required
```

Please assist. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what you'er asking, but as it is, your code is failing because the `.Row` method returns a long/integer value, not a range object. You can't use the `.Copy` method on an integer, so that explains the error.

You could try this to copy only the *last* row in that range (Note: you can do `.Range("A:E")`, there's no reason to use an ampersand to concatenate two string literals, you can simply use the full string "A:E"):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:E").End(xlDown).EntireRow.Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

Or, if you need to copy the entire range to the `.End(xlDown)`, then I think this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E1", Range("A1:E1").End(xlDown)).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

Otherwise, more detail will be needed to assist.